# Can't find an Android library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am using the apdfview project which is on this site

```
http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer
```

but I cant build the source project because it tells me it can't find a library `libpoppler_jni.so` and I cant find it, and although I have the source code in C, I don't know how to build it and generate it.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) and run `ndk-build` on the project to generate that `.so` file, from what I can tell.